# How do do a callback after redirect in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I am redirecting to a page using

```
res.redirect('/pageOne');
```

so after the redirect i want call a function , But when i called the function

```
 res.redirect('/pageOne');
 callBack();
```

I found that the callBack executed before the redirect,

**so there any way to pass callBack to redirect ?** according to the [api](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) its no. any other workaround ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [current implementation](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/8fe1e2a5b45263bcc3c833917ab7bb21ba435215/lib/response.js#L677-717), there is no way to pass a callback into the `redirect` method. However, since the response object `res` [inherits from Node's own `ServerResponse`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/8fe1e2a5b45263bcc3c833917ab7bb21ba435215/lib/response.js#L25-27), which in turn is a [`Writable` stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable), you can watch for the related events. For example, you might try the `finish` event:

> #### Event: 'finish'
>
> When `end()` is called and there are no more chunks to write, this event is emitted.

So, for example,

```
res.on('finish', callback);
res.redirect('/pageOne');
```

Comment: I was hoping (and I guess this is the spirit of the question) the callback would be executed after the following page finished handling the redirected call, but it's not like that: the event is triggered after a couple of milliseconds. Thinking about it, I reckon it's damn difficult to handle this case in a general way (the redirection could go to a completely different server). Still, I'd like to know an express-based solution in the case the redirection is made to a page on the same server app.

Comment: @Muzietto What do you mean? Call the callback after the new URL has finished rendering? Loading? Yes, that will be more difficult, requiring application level code I'd say. All a `redirect` really is is a special header sent in the response, then the response is ended and flushed.